# How to display it on the product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

With this function I am getting the option to use a custom selectbox in my products. But it doesn't appear in the product page meta. I would like to display it just for one special product. How can I do that?

I don't have any PHP experience.

````
<?php
function prefix_add_selectbox() {
  $args = array(
    'id' => 'my_new_select', // required. The meta_key ID for the stored value
    'wrapper_class' => '', // a custom wrapper class if needed
    'desc_tip' => true, // makes your description show up with a "?" symbol and as a tooltip
    'description' => __('My awesome select box', 'your_text_domain'),
    'label' => __( 'My New Select', 'your_text_domain' ),
    'options' => array(
      'value1' => __( 'Text 1', 'your_text_domain' ),
      'value2' => __( 'Text 2', 'your_text_domain' )
    )
  );
  woocommerce_wp_select( $args );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_tax', 'prefix_add_selectbox' );```
````

Comment: Or do you mean that you (also) want to add a select box to a single product page? (frontend), but only for 1 specific product?

Comment: I want to add a select box or a multi-select box to a single product page but only for one specific product. Thank you in advance

Comment: The code that you posted will only works in the backend, if you want to add a select box in the frontend, you will first have to determine where you want to display it on the single product page, see: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ 
every hook has its own properties, the use of a specific hook ensures that your code appears in the right place. 
Based on the chosen hook, you can then start adding code to display text, images, html, etc...